# create two list views were the first list will populate the second list

Tags: c#

best way to have a list of categories and a second list of subcategories when item is clicked in the first list  and when click item in second list opens a new form c# I have tried a listview with a second but have not found a way to populate the second list from the first list

i would like a list of categories and a when clicked item a second list of subcategories shows and when item clicked opens a new form

Comment: How are you storing the list of categories and subcategories? Please add more information about the data. Preferably in the form of a [mre].

Comment: i have a split box and inside the splitbox two listview the first list view has a list of categories and I wish to click on an item and populate the seond listview with clickable subcategories that will open a form I have created already